# I can't create a new instance of a contract from a factory contract when using a js script but unit test ok

Tags: revert, javascript

I have 2 SC:

- Factory contract that creates new instance of the 2nd contract via a function:

```
 function createCollection(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint16 _maxNFT) public onlyOwner {
    uint256 currentYear = getCurrentYear();
    address newCollection = address(new NFTFinance(_name, _symbol, _maxNFT));
    collections[currentYear] = newCollection;
    emit CollectionCreated(newCollection);
  }
```

- ERC 721 contract that mint and transfer NFT. Nothing really fancy, here's the constructor:

```
 constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint16 _maxNFT) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    maxNFT = _maxNFT;
  }
```

I wrote unit test using truffle js and I can easily create new collection of NFTs.

```
it("should create a new NFT collection", async () => {
    const collectionName = "Genesis";
    const collectionSymbol = "CASBF22";
    const maxNumberNFT = 19;
    await factoryInstance.createCollection(collectionName, collectionSymbol, maxNumberNFT);
    //Collection created:
    const currentYear = (await factoryInstance.getCurrentYear()).toString()
    const collectionAddress = await factoryInstance.collections(currentYear);
    assert.notEqual(collectionAddress, "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
    //Check name and symbol:
    nftCollectionInstance = await NFTFinance.at(collectionAddress);
    const name = await nftCollectionInstance.name();
    const symbol = await nftCollectionInstance.symbol();
    assert.equal(name, collectionName);
    assert.equal(symbol, collectionSymbol);
  });
```

I wrote a script in JS as well, and neither with Ganache, neither on Sepolia the transaction passed.
I am using Alchemy, everything is well set up (API_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY, CONTRACT_ADDRESS etc.) I have the same private key I used to deploy the contracts.

My script revert when entering the function.
I fetch the data to create the collection in an excel table but I checked if the parameters are good. On Ganache I could see the good inputs.

I don't understand why I can't even enter the function and why it reverts but I can create new collection with my unit test.

Help will be much appreciate here.

Thanks